# Log requests to nginx as soon as they arrive

Tags: nginx

Nginx's `access_log` logs requests only when their response is complete. Is it possible to configure the web server such that the requests it receives get logged as soon as they arrive?

Comment: I do not think this is possible unless you modify the sources.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @AlexC I want to find out if the generation of any response is hanging.